# OAuth Error when trying to get Token through JavaScript

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, cors, security-token

I am setting up a connected application and am having trouble generating a bearer token through my JS code. I have it working perfectly through postman, as well as all of my get calls, I use postman to generate the JS code and for everything but the token Post it works fine. This is the code I am working with, with all the sensitive fields covered up:

[image: Sample code for token generation]

Furthermore, I am running this code on an HTTPS server and the server is added to my trusted sites and cors list on salesforce (although I don't think it should matter since its accessing https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token). However I still am faced with this error when running this code:

[image: Browser Error]

Please let me know if there is anything that I should change with my code or if there is anything else wrong that would be causing it to work on postman but not in my code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the callout is blocked by your browser because of the CORS policy.

You can read up on CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), and you can whitelist domains in salesforce setup under security > CORS.

Comment: But I do have it there, and it wouldn't matter because the domain that you are trusting with CORS is your personalized salesforce instance, but the domain you are accessing with this post is https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Comment: The domain that has to be trusted is the one that you are accessing salesforce *from*. So the site that is running your code. I.E. the origin in the error message.

Comment: I have that, I needed to add it for Get requests, but it doesn't do anything for the Bearer token post

Comment: I don't know if it's viable for your usecase, but you could try to use yourdomain.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token instead of login.salesforce.com

Comment: This solved it, thank you so much!